# Training with Grey images dataset - MASKRCNN Matterport

Tags: image-segmentation

I'm trying to train a set of custom dataset that are grey images.

The matterport is designed for RGB dataset.

These are the steps that I have followed so far for my grey scale dataset.

**Step 1**

```
> class DetectorConfig(Config):
>     Configuration for training pneumonia detection on the RSNA pneumonia dataset.
>     Overrides values in the base Config class https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/config.py.
>     IMAGE_CHANNEL_COUNT = 1
>     MEAN_PIXEL = [123.7] # this value is the one that I chose
```

**Step 2**

```
> def load_image(self, image_id):
>         # Load image
>         image = skimage.io.imread(self.image_info[image_id]['path'])
>         # Convert to grayscale for consistency.
>         if image.ndim != 1:
>             image = skimage.color.gray2rgb(image) #Instead of rgb2gray(image)
> 
>         # Extending the size of the image to be (h,w,1)
>         image = image[..., np.newaxis]
>         return image
```

**Alternate Step 2**

```
>     def load_image(self, image_id):
>         """Load the specified image and return a [H,W,3] Numpy array.
>         # Load image
>         image = skimage.io.imread(self.image_info[image_id]['path'])         
>         image = image[..., np.newaxis] # Extending the size of the image to be (h,w,1)
>         return image
```

**Alternate Step 2a**

```
>     def load_image(self, image_id):
>         """Load the specified image and return a [H,W,3] Numpy array.
>         # Load image
>         image = cv2.imread(self.image_info[image_id]['path'])         
>         image = image[..., np.newaxis] # Extending the size of the image to be (h,w,1)
>         return image
```

**Step 3**

```
> model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True,
>                         exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc", 
>                                  "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask", "conv1"])
```

**Step 4**

```
>  layer_regex = {
>             # all layers but the backbone
>             "heads": r"(conv1\_.*)|(mrcnn\_.*)|(rpn\_.*)|(fpn\_.*)",
> 

> def load_image(self, image_id):
>      image = image[..., np.newaxis]
```

**Step 5**

```
> def resize_image(image, min_dim=None, max_dim=None, min_scale=None, mode="square"):
> padding = [(top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad)]
> image = np.pad(image, padding, mode='constant', constant_values=0)
```

**Step 6**

```
>  if len(image.shape) != 3 or image.shape[2] != 3:
>         image = np.squeeze(image, axis = -1)
>         image = np.stack((image,) * 3, -1)
```

When I run this code,
I faced this issue from train(model)
ValueError: len(output_shape) cannot be smaller than the image dimensions

The issue is different if I used "rgb2gray(image)" instead at Step 2

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,2) and requested shape (3,2)
```

**Alternate step 2**

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,2) and requested shape (3,2)
```

**Alternate Step 2a**

```
ValueError: len(output_shape) cannot be smaller than the image dimensions
```

Please provide some assistance.
All dataset images are of same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is due to dimension mismatch.

1. Reason for `len(output_shape) cannot be smaller than the image dimensions`: The reason for this is that your source image is 4D (H, W, 3, 1), i.e. 3 channels. Possible reason for this would be

   ```
   image = skimage.color.gray2rgb(image)
   image = image[..., np.newaxis]
   ```

   Here you are first loading the images with 3 channels as then adding a new axis. To avoid this either use `image = skimage.color.gray2rgb(image)` or `image = image[..., np.newaxis]`, but never both together in `load_image`. For reference here is what I used:

   ```
   def load_image(self, image_id):
       """Load the specified image and return a [H,W,3] Numpy array.
       """
       # Load image
       image = skimage.io.imread(self.image_info[image_id]['path'])
       image = image[..., np.newaxis]
       return image
   ```
2. To get to the pertinent question, the reason for `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,2) and requested shape (3,2)` is because your image is 3D (i.e. (H, W, 1) because of `image = image[..., np.newaxis]`) and your padding `padding = [(top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad)]` is 2D. Reverting back to the original padding

   ```
   padding = [(top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad), (0, 0)]
   ```

   will resolve this issue.

Hope this solves your problem.